# Casting `filter object` to `list` clears its contents

Tags: list, python-3.x, filter

When investigating my other issue I ran into a very strange behaviour.

Running the code:

```
def test(prefix, custom_meta_files = []):
  postfix = 'tgz'  
  if prefix[-1] != '.':
    postfix = '.tgz'

  archive = tarfile.open(prefix+postfix, "w:gz")
  files = filter(lambda path: path.startswith(prefix), os.listdir())
  print('files: {0}'.format(list(files)))
  print('files: {0}'.format(list(files)))


files: ['ga_run.seq_niche.N30.1.bt0_5K.params', 'ga_run.seq_niche.N30.1.bt0_5K.stats', 'ga_run.seq_niche.N30.1.bt0_5K.tgz']
files: []
```

It seems like casting `filter object` to a `list` clears it. Why is that so and is it desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
list(files)
```

You're effectively consuming the generator returned by `filter` for creating a list (it's not a "cast" by the way), so the second time you write `list(files)` the generator is already finished. This should fix it, and it's also a good idea to store repeated results in variables - it avoids recalculating values:

```
lst = list(files)
print('files: {0}'.format(lst))
print('files: {0}'.format(lst))
```

Comment: So I was right. I will accept your answer even if essentially its the same as mine, but I don't feel like waiting two days just because I wrote it 1min earlier. I also figured that I can save it and reuse. Initially I thought that filter returns a more `list`-like persistent object not a generator. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I might turn out to be stupid. But I started reading docs again and I think I
 found out the reason. I post it as a self-answer because I think the question is valid and not worth or removing.

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter) says: "Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to the generator expression (item for item in iterable if function(item)) if function is not None and (item for item in iterable if item) if function is None."

So if it acts as a generator probably casting it iterates over the generator and effectively "empties" it.

Still, I would appreciate if any python expert could point if this is the right way of thinking.

Comment: Yes, `filter` returns an generator and casting that generator to a list uses it up. If you need it in list form, your best bet is to cast it to a list and assign that list to a variable.